# Trading View Volume Indikator

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Is it possible to get the Value of the first Volume Bar and safe it in a variable?

Thanks.

Ist it possible to safe the Value of the first Vol. Bar abd safe it in an variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
var first_volume_ = volume
```

This value will not change and will be the volume of the first bar in the dataset of a chart